# Bootstrap align text and image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make divs inline in the card box and doing it also. But text is being vertically centered next to. can not managed the make the text start the top.

```
<div class="card text-left">
       <div class="card-header">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                                </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         <div class="card-body">
      <div class="d-inline"><img src="{{$estate->image}}" id="image"></div>
    <div class="d-inline">{{$estate->building_name}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Try to use `d-inline` for to make image and text side by side. But this time text is being vertically aligned.

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net to visualize it. And what are the problem?.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ubvanw93/3/ here. you can see the text is vertical how can I make it start at top.

Comment: Now what output do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `d-inline-flex` and `align-top`

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="d-inline-flex"><img src="{{$estate->image}}" id="image"></div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex align-top">{{$estate->building_name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Barbie Welcome)